# How to pass an array of doubles from VB6 to VC++..What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, vb6

How to pass an array of doubles from VB6 to VC++..What is wrong with this code?

**VB Code:** dSelfCdArr is my array of double values

```
Public Sub FilterDocTypeByPriv(colEventSets As Collection)

Dim lCount As Long
Dim oColItem As Object
Dim objDBEventSetRow As DB_EventSetRow
Dim evYes As Boolean
Dim dSelfCdArr() As Double
For lCount = 1 To colEventSets.Count
    Set objDBEventSetRow = colEventSets(lCount)
    ReDim Preserve dSelfCdArr(1 To lCount)
    dSelfCdArr(lCount) = CDbl(objDBEventSetRow.dSelf_cd)
Next

Call m_dtsAppForm.DocController.HasPrivCreateResultEventCode(m_dUserId, m_dPositionCd, m_dPPRCd, dSelfCdArr)
End Sub
```

**C++ Idl file:**

```
[id(51), helpstring("method HasPrivCreateResultEventCode")] HRESULT HasPrivCreateResultEventCode([in]double dUserId,[in]double dPosCd,[in]double dPPRCd, [in, out] VARIANT* pEventCode);
```

**C++ Code:** I get bad pointers in the first line for VARIANT* pEventCode

```
STDMETHODIMP CDocumentController::HasPrivCreateResultEventCode(double dUserId,double dPosCd,double dPPRCd, VARIANT* pEventCode)
{   

HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())

if (V_VT(pEventCode) == VT_ARRAY | VT_R8)
{
    CComSafeArray<double> arrECode;

    arrECode.Attach(pEventCode->parray);

    double pVals;

    int iCount = arrECode.GetCount();

    CMap<double,double,bool,bool> mapEventCds;

    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < iCount; iIndex++)
    {                              
        double pVals = arrECode.GetAt(iIndex);

        mapEventCds.SetAt(pVals, false);

        std::cout << "element " << iIndex << ": value = " << pVals << std::endl;
    }

    CheckPrivViewResultEventCds(dUserId, dPosCd, dPPRCd, mapEventCds);
                //pEventCode->c

    double      dEventCd(0.0);
    bool        bPriv(false);
    POSITION    pos(mapEventCds.GetStartPosition());
    INT_PTR     nEventCnt(mapEventCds.GetCount());

    CComSafeArray<double> pSafeArraypEventCode = NULL;
    for(INT_PTR count(0); count < nEventCnt; ++count)
    {
        mapEventCds.GetNextAssoc(pos, dEventCd, bPriv);     
        if (bPriv)
        {   
            pSafeArraypEventCode.Add(dEventCd);
        }
    }

    pEventCode->parray = pSafeArraypEventCode.Detach();
    // Empty the CMap
    mapEventCds.RemoveAll();

}
return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: `==` has higher [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `|`. In other words: Your `if`-statement doesn't do what you think. It always evaluates to `true`. You need to rewrite that to `if(V_VT(pEventCode) == (VT_ARRAY|VT_R8))`.

Comment: No it doesn't.  See my answer.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and tell us what `dSelfCdArr` evaluates to in VB?

Comment: its an array of double... 
dSelfCdArr(1) : 3063615896 : Double : ...                 dSelfCdArr(2) : 3065369201 : Double : and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the answer**..I had to destroy the original safearray data, create a new safearray to fill the data from maps and then copy the new safearray data to the original safearray using SafeArrayCopy.. It worked.

```
STDMETHODIMP CDocumentController::GetEventCodesWithAddDocumentationPriv(double dUserId,double dPosCd,double dPPRCd,SAFEARRAY** pArrayOfEventCode)
{ 

HRESULT lResult(S_OK); // return code for OLE functions

// checking if it is a one-dimensional array
if ( (*pArrayOfEventCode)->cDims != 1 ) 
{
    MsgWrite(MSG_DEFAULT, eMsgLog_Commit, _T("PVClinDocMiscCom"), eMsgLvl_Error, _T("CDocumentController::GetEventCodesWithAddDocumentationPriv() SafeArray pEventCode is not one dimensional"));
    return(E_FAIL);
}

// locking the array before using its elements
lResult=SafeArrayLock(*pArrayOfEventCode);
if (lResult != S_OK)
{   
    MsgWrite(MSG_DEFAULT, eMsgLog_Commit, _T("PVClinDocMiscCom"), eMsgLvl_Error, _T("CDocumentController::GetEventCodesWithAddDocumentationPriv() SafeArray pEventCode is not locked"));
    SafeArrayUnlock(*pArrayOfEventCode);
    return(E_FAIL);
}

double *pArrayOfElements; // pointer to the elements of the array
// using the array
pArrayOfElements=(double*) (*pArrayOfEventCode)->pvData;

CMap<double,double,bool,bool> mapEventCds;

// number of elements in the array
long lElements=(*pArrayOfEventCode)->rgsabound[0].cElements;
double lVal(0);
for (long lCount=0; lCount<lElements; lCount++) 
{ 
    lVal = pArrayOfElements[lCount]; 
    mapEventCds.SetAt(lVal, false); 
} 

CheckPrivViewResultEventCds(dUserId, dPosCd, dPPRCd, mapEventCds); 

SafeArrayUnlock(*pArrayOfEventCode);
lResult = SafeArrayDestroyData(*pArrayOfEventCode);
if (lResult != S_OK)
{   
    MsgWrite(MSG_DEFAULT, eMsgLog_Commit, _T("PVClinDocMiscCom"), eMsgLvl_Error, _T("CDocumentController::GetEventCodesWithAddDocumentationPriv() SafeArray could not be destroyed"));
    return(E_FAIL);
}

SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1]; //Create a one dimensional array
rgsabound[0].lLbound = (*pArrayOfEventCode)->rgsabound->lLbound; //Set the lowerbound for the array
rgsabound[0].cElements = (*pArrayOfEventCode)->rgsabound->cElements; //Set the upperbound for the array

//Create a new safearray of double to fill from the mapeventcodes
SAFEARRAY* newArray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8, 1, rgsabound);

double          dEventCd(0.0); 
bool            bPriv(false);
//Get the starting index of the SafeArray
long lEventCdIdx = (*pArrayOfEventCode)->rgsabound->lLbound;
POSITION pos(mapEventCds.GetStartPosition()); 
while(pos != NULL)
{ 
    mapEventCds.GetNextAssoc(pos, dEventCd, bPriv); 
    if (bPriv) 
    {   
        lResult = SafeArrayPutElement(newArray, &lEventCdIdx, &dEventCd);
        if (lResult != S_OK)
        {   
            MsgWrite(MSG_DEFAULT, eMsgLog_Commit, _T("PVClinDocMiscCom"), eMsgLvl_Debug, _T("CDocumentController::GetEventCodesWithAddDocumentationPriv() Failed to add element to array"));
        }
        lEventCdIdx++;
    }   
}

// Empty the CMap 
mapEventCds.RemoveAll(); 
//Copy the contents from new safearray to the existing safearray
SafeArrayCopy(newArray, pArrayOfEventCode);
//Destroy the new safearray
SafeArrayDestroy(newArray);
// releasing the array 

return S_OK;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
if (V_VT(pEventCode) == VT_ARRAY | VT_R8)
```

The VB equivalent to that would be:

```
If V_VT(pEventCode) = VT_ARRAY Or True Then
//Do stuff
End If
```

The `| VT_R8` is evaluating to boolean `true` because:
1) `==` takes precedence over `|`, so the comparison is performed, THEN `VT_R8` is evaluated.
And
2) Anything that is non-zero equals "true" in C.  Since `VT_R8` gets evaluated by itself (and not as part of the comparison), it is always `true`.

You need to use parentheses so that your statements are evaluated in the order you want.

Comment: That's only one of the problems. The array is passed as a SAFEARRAY. SAFEARRAYs have lower and upper bounds associated with them. The lower bound does not necessarily have to be 0, so the `for`-loop will in general fail.

Comment: Should it be like this? **if (V_VT(pEventCode) == (VT_ARRAY | VT_R8))**

Comment: Yes.  I would even use short-circuiting OR (`||`) instead.

Comment: `||` will not make the expression any more readable. `VT_R8` is a type while `VT_ARRAY` is a flag (semantically). Only a variant of type `VT_R8|VT_ARRAY` is a SAFEARRAY of double precision floating point values.

Comment: If you propose a semantically identical rewrite of an expression that doesn't improve readability what else should it improve on? Also, your explanation of how the original expression is evaluated is wrong. `VT_R8` is **not** evaluated by itself, but rather bitwise OR'ed with the left-hand side. `|` is a bitwise OR operator, not a logical OR (`||`).

Comment: I modified the if condition. But the condition becomes false as I have a null pointer at the beginning..

Comment: Then you need to check for `null`.

Comment: And FYI, anything that is `OR`'ed with boolean `true`, whether bitwise or not, is ALWAYS equivalent to boolean `true` in C.

Comment: But my pEventCode at the beginning has bad pointers.. Is my VB code fine?

Comment: There is no bitwise OR defined for the `bool` type. A `bool` on either side of a bitwise OR operator is propagated to a compatible integer type. The result of that expression is not `true` either; it is of integer type. Integer types can be implicitly converted to `bool`. Even if they come to the same conclusion, both of your explanations are wrong. In addition, there is no `bool`, `true` or `false` in C (until C99, which is not implemented in Visual Studio).

Comment: The explanation seems fine to me. `Or` in VB does double-duty as a bitwise OR and a logical operator.

Comment: @Jonathan I was referring to the text stating that `VT_R8` will be evaluated by itself. Now that is clearly not the case.

Comment: `HasPrivCreateResultEventCode(double dUserId,double dPosCd,double dPPRCd, VARIANT* pEventCode)`... ...............`pEventCode` is passed from VB. The `pEventCode` is a null pointer. There is something that is missed while sending the Dim **dSelfCdArr()** As Double from VB to VC. Need help to figure that out

Comment: [How To Pass Arrays Between Visual Basic and C](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207931).

Comment: I have followed the same in my vb code..Have I missed anything?

Comment: @Guruprasad Your IDL shows a `VARIANT*` parameter type. The link I posted uses a `SAFEARRAY*`. Also note that your C++ method signature doesn't match the IDL. If you specify `[in,out]` your C++ method needs another pointer indirection.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable.. Finally it worked for me..Will post the final code after optimizing..